# Anticommutativity of wedge product: $sgn( \tau )=(-1)^{kl}$

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I'm trying to write the proof of the following proposition.

**Proposition:** if $f \in A_k(V)$ and $g \in A_l(V)$ then $f \wedge g = (-1)^{kl} g \wedge f$.

[Part 1 of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOpPZ.png)
[- Part 2 of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c4vV.png)

$A_k(V)$ and $A_l(V)$ are the spaces of the alternating k-tensors and l-tensors, respectively, in a vector space V of finite dimension.

I understand the identidy $A(f\otimes g)=sgn(\tau)A(g\otimes f)$ and the necessity of changing the indexes that $\tau$ makes , but, i don't have the insight to calculate $sgn(\tau)$

$$ \tau = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1&\cdots&l&l+1 &\cdots&l+k\\
  k+1&\cdots&k+l&1 &\cdots&k
\end{array}
\right] .$$

The images are from the book Introduction to Manifolds from Loring W. Tu. Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: If you're struggling for general insight, I would recommend doing some small cases first. Can you understand what's going on for $k,l\in\{1,2,3\}$, for instance?

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying and got the following calculations: for $k=l=1$, $\tau=(1 \ 2)$; for $k=1,l=2$, $\tau = (1 \ 2)(2 \ 3)$; for $k=1,l=3$, $\tau = (1 \ 2)(2 \ 3)(3 \ 4)$. And here I see $sgn(\tau)=(-1)^{kl}$. But, for $k=2,l=3$, $\tau = (1 \ 3)(3 \ 5)(2 \ 4)$ and for $k=3,l=3$, $\tau = (1 \ 4)(4 \ 3)(3 \ 6)(2 \ 5)$ and $sgn(\tau)$ not what i expected.

Comment: There's something wrong about the way i've been writing the permutations?

Comment: I think your error lies in your calculations for the larger $k$ - let's look at $k=2$, $l=3$. Remember that in order to go from, say, $c\wedge d\wedge e\wedge a\wedge b$ to $a\wedge b \wedge c\wedge d\wedge e$, we have to bring $a$ across $c\wedge d\wedge e$ and then do the same for $b$ - each of these should be an instance of $k=1$ and $l=3$, right?

Comment: Ohhhh yes!! Now I understand the reason. Thank you so much. In order to write the complete proof, is it enough to observe this fact of the inversions and complete the proof?

Comment: Because calculating these inversions for the general case will become hard

Comment: I think it would be sufficient, yes. Why don't you write up your own proof and post it as an answer to this question, and then we can see how you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From KReiser's explanations, here's my answer to this question:

We want to write $\tau$ as product of inversions in order to calculate $sgn(\tau)$. To do this, we have to turn $\tau$ into the identity permutation of $S_{k+l}$. So we must to move the elements $1,...,k$ across the elements $k+1,...,k+l$.

Starting by the element 1, we multiply $\tau$ on the left by the $l$ transpositions $((l+k) \ \ 1),...,((k+1) \ \  1)$, respectively, to obtain

$$ ((k+1) \ \ 1)\cdots((k+l) \ \  1) \ \tau = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1&\cdots&l&l+1 &\cdots&l+k\\
  1&\cdots&k+l-1&k+l &\cdots&k
\end{array}
\right] .$$

Doing the same process to $2,...,k$, that is, moving $2,...,k$ across $k+1,...,k+l$ we have

$$ ((k+1) \ \ k)\cdots((k+l) \ \  k) \cdots ((k+1) \ \ 1)\cdots((k+l) \ \  1) \ \tau = id .$$

Multiplying both sides of the equation above on the left by the corresponding transpositions we get

$$ \tau= 
\underbrace{ \underbrace{ ((k+l) \ \ 1) \cdots ((k+1) \ \  1) }_{l\text{ times}} \cdots \underbrace{((k+l) \ \ k)\cdots((k+l) \ \  k)}_{l\text{ times}} }_{k \text{ times}}.$$

And therefore,

$$ sgn(\tau)= \underbrace{ (-1)^{l} \cdots (-1)^{l}}_{k\text{ times}} = (-1)^{kl} .$$

The notation is a bit overwhelmed, but I finally got the insight on how to calculate the permutation signal simply by switching positions.

Comment: The proof might get a little bit simpler or clearer using induction, but this looks good.

Comment: how can i prove it by induction?

Comment: I think you have successfully solved your own problem here, +1. Good work, and keep this strategy of trying small cases in your back pocket for the next problem you face.

Answer (score 0):

Just counting the number of inversions is enough.The number of inversions ending in 1 is l. Namely (k+1,1) to (k+l,1). Similarly The number of inversions ending in 2 is l. Namely (k+1,2) to (k+l,2). Similarly, for no. of inversions ending in each of 3,4....k is l. These are all the inversions. Clearly, the total number of inversions is kl.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).